# admob interstitial manifest changes automatically

Tags: android, admob, android-manifest, interstitial

I have an android app. I want to set interstitial ad,
I put this in the manifest.

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

but it changes into this

```
android:name="com.google.gms.ads.AdActivity"
```

and the log cat show me this `Could not find com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity, please make sure it is declared in AndroidManifest.xml.`

Comment: can you please post AndroidManifest.xml code ? or have you declare with in <application> tag ?

Comment: did you added Google Play Services as a library project?

Comment: yes this is the code
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

Change it back.

It sounds like your IDE (I assume you are using Android Studio - you didn't say) is assuming a particular class. Just change the XML.